# @Input() is not working when selector is enclosed in HTML Tag - Angular 2

Tags: angular, input, angularjs-directive, angular2-template

In my `Angular2` app there is a component called `TabTitleComponent`.

```
       import { Component, OnInit,Input,AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

      @Component({
        selector: 'tab-title',
        templateUrl: './tab-title.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./tab-title.component.css']
      })
      export class TabTitleComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

        @Input() title;

        ngOnInit()
        {
          console.log('ngOnInit'+this.title);
        }
        ngAfterViewInit()
        {
          console.log('ngAfterViewInit',this.title);
        }

      }
```

I am using this component in my `AppComponent`.

> Problem 1

When I use `TabTitleComponent` in HTML(`AppComponent`'s Template) as following then I am not getting `title` value. In console it is logging `undefined`.

```
 <div>
   <tab-title [title]='88'> </tab-title>     
</div>
```

when I replace it with following then I am getting `88` in console.

```
 <tab-title [title]='88'> </tab-title>
```

> Problem 2

When I make `title` of `string` type and pass value then in both cases I am getting `undefined`.

I am not able to find the root cause. Can someone helps me to find out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the reason in "88"
Try this code:

```
<tab-title [title]="'88'"> </tab-title>
```

Comment: After using `"'name'"` it is working. It is weird . why so? @Max

Comment: "name" - is variable in ts file and " 'name' " - just a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Input, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'


@Component({
  selector: 'tab-title',
  template: '<div>{{title}}</div>'
})
export class TabTitleComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

  @Input() title : string;

  ngOnInit()
  {
    console.log('ngOnInit'+this.title);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit',this.title);
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
     <tab-title [title]="'88'"> </tab-title>     
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, TabTitleComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: when i used `"'name'" it is working. What is the reason behind its working?